# Should parquet filter pushdown reduce data read?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a data set stored in parquet with several short key fields and one relatively large (several kb) blob field. The data set is sorted by key1, key2.

```
message spark_schema {
  optional binary key1 (UTF8);
  optional binary key2;
  optional binary blob;
}
```

One use case of this dataset is to fetch all the blobs for a given predicate of key1, key2. I would expect parquet predicate pushdown to help greatly by not reading blobs from rowgroups where the predicate on the keys matched zero records. That does not appear to be the case, however.

For a predicate that only returns 2 rows (out of 6 million), this query:

```
select sum(length(blob)) from t2 where key1 = 'rare value'
```

takes 5x longer and reads 50x more data (according to the web UI) than this query:

```
select sum(length(key2)) from t2 where key1 = 'rare value'
```

The parquet scan does appear to be getting the predicate (says `explain()`, see below), and those columns do even appear to be dictionary encoded (see further below).

So does parquet filter pushdown not actually allow us to read less data or is there something wrong with my setup?

---

```
scala> spark.sql("select sum(length(blob)) from t2 where key1 = 'rare value'").explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[sum(cast(length(blob#48) as bigint))])
+- Exchange SinglePartition
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_sum(cast(length(blob#48) as bigint))])
      +- *Project [blob#48]
         +- *Filter (isnotnull(key1#46) && (key1#46 = rare value))
            +- *BatchedScan parquet [key1#46,blob#48] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: hdfs://nameservice1/user/me/parquet_test/blob, PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(key1), EqualTo(key1,rare value)], ReadSchema: struct<key1:string,blob:binary>



$ parquet-tools meta example.snappy.parquet 
creator:     parquet-mr (build 32c46643845ea8a705c35d4ec8fc654cc8ff816d) 
extra:       org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata = {"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"key1","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"key2","type":"binary","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{" [more]...

file schema: spark_schema 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
key1:        OPTIONAL BINARY O:UTF8 R:0 D:1
key2:        OPTIONAL BINARY R:0 D:1
blob:        OPTIONAL BINARY R:0 D:1

row group 1: RC:3971 TS:320593029 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
key1:         BINARY SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:4 SZ:84/80/0.95 VC:3971 ENC:BIT_PACKED,PLAIN_DICTIONARY,RLE
key2:         BINARY SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:88 SZ:49582/53233/1.07 VC:3971 ENC:BIT_PACKED,PLAIN_DICTIONARY,RLE
blob:         BINARY SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:49670 SZ:134006918/320539716/2.39 VC:3971 ENC:BIT_PACKED,RLE,PLAIN
```

*(repeats...)*

Comment: I reverted your edit back to r1; you forgot to remove (Solved) from the title, which is not appropriate here. You indicate the problem is solved by either writing a self-answer (which you've done) and then accept it as the correct one, or waiting until someone else posts an answer you want to accept.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm still learning the ropes here.

Answer (score 2):

It was pointed out to me on the spark user list that there's a few bugs in parquet affecting current versions of spark and ultimately breaking predicate pushdown for binary and string types. My use case works as expected with integer keys. Fixed in Parquet 1.8.1. See [PARQUET-251](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-251) and [PARQUET-297](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-297) for details. (hat tip: Robert Kruszewski).

Comment: ...and my original scenario works w/o modification on the spark-2.1 nightly from 2016-09-02. yay.

Answer (score 0):

It should work now when using Spark 2.1.0 with the following meta displayed :

```
creator: parquet-mr version 1.8.1 (build 4aba4dae7bb0d4edbcf7923ae1339f28fd3f7fcf)
```

When writing new data.